# Disable first character in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and it contain a value "Given Name". I want to disable first character of a textbox so that user cannot change the First Charcter in textbox by using backspace or any other means.
For Example: suppose textbox contains the value "Given Name". I want that user cannot change the First character "G" by using backspace or any other means.

```
<input type="text" id="nameId" onkeydown="validate(this.val)"/>
```

Below is javascript function:

```
function validate2(val) {
  // have no idea how to do.

}
```

I have no idea how to do it in Javscript or Jquery.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You could use `keyup` event, check if the first character is a G, if not, add it.

Comment: Just a quick note: They will still be able to do it by right clicking, inspecting the element and changing the value that way. So what I mean is that you should *not* trust the client side.

Comment: @DavidMulder Even more than this onKeyDown triggers when keys are pressed, highlighting with the mouse and cutting the text with the right click menu would also work. Never trust the client, always double check the input, and anything that hasn't been checked and sanitised should never be used as output or go near the database(even using PDO and parametrised queries you're not protecting against bad inputs, only injection attacks, a price of -1 for an item, or 9,999,999,999 as a quantity isn't going to be stopped unless you check for it).

Comment: Check my solution, let me know if there is anything missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like follow :

```
$("#nameId").on("keydown", function(e) {
  // if user writes a char at index === 0 that is not an arrow or HOME or END
  if (($(this).get(0).selectionStart === 0 && (e.keyCode < 35 || e.keyCode > 40))
    // or if user tries to erase first char
    || ($(this).get(0).selectionStart === 1 && $(this).get(0).selectionEnd === 1 && e.keyCode === 8)) {
    // don't write the character
    return false;
  }
});

// prevent right click
$("#nameId").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zfT2/26/)**

Comment: Ill +1 this. Good job.

Comment: we can still delete it now. select the first letter or all letters and then right click on mouse and then select cut.

Comment: Hmmm, nice one. Corrected it ! =)

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't planning on answering, leaving it with the comment, but after seeing the other answers thought I might have a quick go at it after all:

The html:

```
<input type="text" id="nameId" value="Given Name" onkeydown="save(this,event)" onkeyup="restore(this,event)" onchange="restore(this,event)"/>
```

The javascript:

```
function restore(el,event) {
    if(el.value.length == 0){
        el.value = el.dataset.value.substr(0,1);
    }else{
        el.dataset.value = el.value;
    }
}
function save(el,event) {
    var key = event.which || event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if((key === 8 && el.value.length === 1)
           || (key === 46 && el.selectionStart == 0 && el.value.length === 1)){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(el.value.length > 0){
        el.dataset.value = el.value;
    }
}
```

The approach was to not mess around too much with preventing the deletion of the actual character (just the very bare basics) and instead ensure that if somebody deletes the first character to always restore it somehow. It creates code that's easy to comprehend and maintain, yet works quite neatly. A fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLd3n/1/) as well. <s>Do note though that `event.which` is not the most cross browser consistent interface, so either use jQuery for that or check in other browsers before using it in production.</s> Edited it in a way that should work cross browser including older browsers.

Comment: +1 I quite like this one. Pitty about the `event.which` though

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
<input type="text" id="nameId" value="Given Name" onkeydown="validate(this.value,event)"/>
    <script>

       function validate(val,event) {
            // have no idea how to do.
            if(event.target.selectionStart != undefined && (event.which === 46 ||event.which === 8)){
                var startPos = event.target.selectionStart,
                endPos = event.target.selectionEnd;
                 console.log(startPos,endPos);
                if(startPos === 0 && startPos != endPos){
                    var restPart = val.slice(endPos,val.length);
                    if(restPart){
                        val = val[0].concat(restPart);
                    } else{
                        val = val[0] 
                    }
                    event.target.value = val;
                    event.preventDefault();  
                } else if(startPos === 0 && startPos === endPos && event.which === 46){
                   event.preventDefault();  
                } else if(startPos === 1 && event.which === 8){
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }

            }
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Can still select it and delete it.

Comment: You can select the last character but you can't delete it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kLd3n/. Select all characters in the input field and hit delete / backspace. Or, put cursor in front of G and hit delete. It magically disappears ;)

Comment: Go to position 0, hit delete. It will readd the first character thus giving 'GGiven name' if 'Given name' was in the field first. http://jsfiddle.net/C7Ybp/

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine version.

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="nameId" value="Given Name" />
```

**JS**

```
var lastentry = ''; 

$("#nameId").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var targetValue = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
    var targetValueLength =  targetValue.length;
    var inputValue = this.value;

    if(checkChanges(targetValueLength, targetValue, inputValue))
        this.value = targetValue + lastentry;
    else
        lastentry = this.value.slice(targetValueLength)
});

function checkChanges(targetValueLength, targetValue, inputValue)
{
     for(var i = 0; i < targetValueLength ; i++)
    {
        if(targetValue[i] != inputValue[i])        
            return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bn4dS/6/)

Answer (score -2):

Hi use this it do not allow to  delete first character ,

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e)
  {

   var value =  $('#nameId').val().length;

    if ( e.keyCode == 8 && value < 2)
       e.preventDefault();
   });
```